# ASP.NET MVC ViewBag in confirm message box

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, confirm, viewbag

I am passing a message into a viewbag in my controller using a store procedure.

The value string "The order is Invalid" is stored in a sql store procedure which then gets passed into the controller through a model.

I then pass this model value into a ViewBag to be used in the View, however when I call the confirm message box it doesn't prompt when using the ViewBag:

This doesn't work (Has ViewBag.Message):

```
<button type="submit" name="CreateEdit" value="Update Order" onclick="return confirm(ViewBag.Message + 'Put Store Procedure Message here')">Save Update and Message Button</button>
```

This message confirm box works but its not using a ViewBag.

```
<button type="submit" name="CreateEdit" value="Update Order" onclick="return confirm('Put Store Procedure Message here from ViewBag? ')">Save WHY!!!</button>
```

Can you use this confirming box with a ViewBag?

Answer (score 3):

You need:

```
<button type="submit" name="CreateEdit" value="Update Order" 
   onclick="return confirm('@ViewBag.Message')">Save Update and Message Button</button>
```

note the @ in front of the ViewBag to indicate to Razor that it is using the ViewBag object and the single quotes to indicate to the browser that this is a JavaScript string.

Answer (score 2):

In order to do this the un-obtrusive way to detach your JavaScript from your html.

You could attach the message as a data attribute and then read it within your confirm message:

```
<button id="btnSubmit" type="submit" name="CreateEdit" value="Update Order"  
     data-message="@ViewBag.Message">Save WHY!!!</button>

$(function(){

    $( "#btnSubmit" ).click(function() {
      var message = $(this).data('message');
      return confirm(message)
    });

})
```

This would also provide the benefit of allowing your JavaScript to be in an external file that could be minified.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzypg1ts/1/)**

Comment: This is a nice approach and decouples the data from the implementation.

Comment: This is very nice indeed. 

I tried using javascript but I failed, I was linking back to my controller and trying to return a error message.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding @ to ViewBag, like

```
<button type="submit" name="CreateEdit" value="Update Order" onclick="return confirm('@ViewBag.Message' + 'Put Store Procedure Message here')">Save Update and Message Button</button>
```

?

Comment: that won't work because your viewbag value will be seen as a JS variable name if not include between the quotes like this `'@ViewBag.Message Put Store Procedure Message here'`

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing the "@"

```
<button type="submit" name="CreateEdit" value="Update Order" onclick="return confirm('@ViewBag.Message ')">Save Update and Message Button</button>
```